# Glossary makes a text-based mathematical operator bold

Tags: luatex, math-operators, bold, scrbook, glossaries-extra

I wrote a document `myfile.tex` using `KOMA-Script`'s `scrbook` document class. I created a mathematical operator named `\cent` from the textual symbol for a cent. I added a glossary to my document using the `glossaries-extra` package, and inserted an entry into this glossary for the mathematical cent operator that I'd created.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\newcommand{\cent}{\operatorname{\text{\textcolonmonetary}}}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{cent}{name={\ensuremath{\cent}},description={cent}}
\begin{document}
$\cent$\glsadd{cent}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

After compiling the code:

```
lualatex myfile
makeglossaries myfile
lualatex myfile
```

the result was that the cent operator in the glossary printed in boldface.

[image: A bold glossary entry]

I should mention that this was the only glossary entry out of dozens in my actual original document that was formatted in boldface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `\operatorname`? Anyway, instead of `\text` that will pick up the surrounding font parameters, you should use `\textnormal`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\newcommand{\cent}{\operatorname{\textnormal{\textcolonmonetary}}}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{cent}{name={\ensuremath{\cent}},description={cent}}
\begin{document}
$\cent$\glsadd{cent}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should be aware that `\textcolonmonetary` isn't “cent”, but the symbol of the colón used in Costa Rica. Maybe you want `\textcent`.

Comment: Thanks. In reply to your question why `\operatorname`: because it's meant to be a unitary operator, like `\sin`. Also, thanks for the clarification regarding the colón. Another good reason to visit to Costa Rica.